# Calling & reading results from a procedure in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, procedure

I am trying to run the below mentioned procedure in hibernate but I don't know how to do it?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadData(
aircraft_id1 bigint, provider_fl_id varchar(32), city1 varchar(32), time1 timestamp, fare decimal(10,4), 
city2 varchar(32), time2 timestamp)
        BEGIN
                DECLARE flId bigint default 0;
                DECLARE rId int default 0;
                DECLARE r_id bigint default 0;
                DECLARE seat_no int default 0;
                SET rId=-1;
                SET flId=-1;
                SET r_id=-1;
                SET seat_no=-1;
                SELECT flight_id into flId from flight_schedule where
aircraft_id=aircraft_id1 and
                ((from_datetime > time1 and from_datetime < time2) or (to_datetime >
time1 and to_datetime < time2)) limit 1;
                if flId < 0 THEN
                    Select count(*) into rId from route where source=city1 and destination=city2;
                        if rId < 1 THEN
                            Insert into route(source,destination) values(city1,city2);
                        end if;                     
                        Select route_id into r_id from route where source=city1 and destination=city2;
                        Select seats into seat_no from aircraft where aircraft_id=aircraft_id1;
                        Insert into flight_schedule(route_id, aircraft_id, provider_flight_id,
                            from_datetime, to_datetime, seats, fare) values(r_id,
                                aircraft_id1, provider_fl_id, time1, time2, seat_no ,fare);
                Select "Success" as Result;
                else Select "Failure" as Reuslt;
                end if;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using below code but its not working.

```
HibernateUtil
                            .getSession()
                            .createSQLQuery(
                                    "CALL (:aircraftId, :providerFlightId, :city1,:time1,:fare,:city2,:time2)")
                            .addEntity(String.class)
                            .setParameter("aircraftId", row[0])
                            .setParameter("providerFlightId", row[1])
                            .setParameter("city1", row[2])
                            .setParameter("time1", row[3])
                            .setParameter("fare", row[4])
                            .setParameter("city2", row[5])
                            .setParameter("time2", row[6]);
```

I think i have to call addEntity() as well but i don't know what class will work?
Any link,help or reference will be appreciable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using createSqlQuery method & running it simply without use of addEntity or setParameter.
Also the result shown at mysql terminal should be the list type of resultset.
Let me know if you want more clarification.
Thank you.